# short int as type in a template

Tags: c++, templates

I made this function to convert a vector into a valarray:

```
template <typename T> valarray<T>* ValArrayTools::vectorToValArray(vector<T>* vector) {
valarray<T>* val = new valarray<T>(vector->size());
for(int i = 0; i < vector->size(); i++)
{
    val[i] = vector[i];
}
return val;
```

}

I tried to use a template so that I can use this function with every possible type.

Now I want to convert a

```
vector<short int> buffer;
```

into a

```
valarray<short int>* data;
```

by using

```
sf->data = ValArrayTools::vectorToValArray<short int>(&buffer);
```

But I get this error:

```
CMakeFiles\LPC-Vocoder_Tests.dir/objects.a(ShortFileLoader.cpp.obj): In function `ZN15ShortFileLoader17generateShortFileEv':
C:/Users/****/Documents/Uni/SS18/**Projekt/LPC-Vocoder/src/ShortFileLoader.cpp:33: undefined reference to `std::valarray<short>* ValArrayTools::vectorToValArray<short>(std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >*)'
```

Comment: Implement the method inside the header. Not in the `cpp`.

Comment: Looks like you might have your template split in a .h and .cpp file, you can't do that.  Also there is not reason to use pointers here at all.  You function could be written as: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db3eb466a1a069e7

Comment: When the template is called, if the definition is not visible to the compiler, it'll assume that someone else will instantiate the function and generate a link to it.  But nobody else instantiates it, so you get the link error.  Moving the def to the header will make it visible and allow it to be instantiated.

Comment: I moved the code into the header and now it compiles. But now i get a segmentation fault and my debugger still says that its just a std::valarray<short>*

Comment: short == short int

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it substantially changes the question (the comments and the duplicate no longer apply). You're better off posting a completely new question with a [mcve].